# i want to animate this logo but for some reason it doesn't work

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="340px" height="333px" viewBox="0 0 340 333" enable-background="new 0 0 340 333" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <style>
        .path {
            stroke-dasharray: 1000;
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
        }

        @keyframes dash {
            from {
                stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
            }
            to {
                stroke-dashoffset: 0;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <title>logo</title>
    <path class="path" d="M115.59,123.26l39.56-31c0.63-.5-0.26-1.38-0.88-0.88l-39.56,31c-0.63.5,0.26,1.38,0.88,0.88h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
    <path class="path" d="M94.71,73.09l35.54-.51a0.63,0.63,0,0,0,0-1.25l-35.54.51a0.63,0.63,0,0,0,0,1.25h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
    <path class="path" d="M95.1,121.61l0-86.41V22.81a0.63,0.63,0,0,0-1.25,0l0,86.41v12.39a0.63,0.63,0,0,0,1.25,0h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
    <path class="path" d="M155.15,91.35l-15.9-19.21c-0.51-.62-1.39.27-0.88,0.88l15.9,19.21c0.51,0.62,1.39-.27.88-0.88h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
    <path class="path" d="M154.57,52.56L138.36,72.14c-0.51.62,0.37,1.5,0.88,0.88l16.21-19.58c0.51-.62-0.37-1.5-0.88-0.88h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
    <path class="path" d="M114.71,22.13l39.56,31c0.63,0.49,1.52-.39.88-0.88l-39.56-31c-0.63-.49-1.52.39-0.88,0.88h0Z" transform="translate(-93.82 -21.1)" />
</svg>
```

i want this svg logo to looks like its drawn with css animation. can someone help me fix this problem. its already on the page it doesn't animate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, your svg doesn't have a stroke (what you see is actually the fill). Remove the fill and add a stroke, and your animation will kick in:

```
.path {
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;

    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
    animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}
```